# When .nil leads to error and <1 does not, are there any more elegant ways to do it?

Tags: ruby, mongodb

Just fixed a bug when if Something.nil? was yielding false when Something did not exist.
Somthing.count.nil? led to the same result
Fixed it by if Something.count < 1

Why could this not be working?
Any better ways than if x < 1 ?

Comment: It was working. If it had a value it was by definition not nil.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [zero?](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Fixnum.html#method-i-zero-3F) on Something.count

```
0.zero? # true
```

The reason for your "error" is that 0.nil? is false.  0 is not nil.

If you are testing for 0 elements in an array or a hash, use [empty?](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Array.html#method-i-empty-3F) on Something.

```
[].empty? # true
Something.empty? # true
```